Why would people invest in T-Bills over an extended period of time, when more tax-efficient options like BOXX exist?
Assuming a retail investor holds/rolls T-Bills for years, is there any reason for a retail investor to buy T-Bills directly when tax-efficient ETFs like BOXX exist (that provide the same return as T-Bills while being taxed at LTCG rate if held for a year)?
Does investor take on any other risks besides the counterparty risk when purchasing this ETF? The counterparty in this case is Options Clearing Corporation (OCC), which has the same credit rating as the US government.

If you buy a Treasury, you lock in the rate.  The credit for box spreads fluctuates so if rates drop, BOXX will underperform the Treasury.  The potential LTCG of BOXX is attractive.

Thanks @BobBaerker! That makes sense.. So I guess for people that hold very short term t-bills (to have cash on hand) boxx is a no-brainer?

If you mean days or weeks, BOXX makes more sense, especially if your broker offers less than stellar rates.

Assuming you are in the twilight of your career and have been planning your retirement during the non-inflationary period prior to Covid.  A safe withdrawal rate of 4% might have seemed optimistic and maybe you planned for 3.5 or even 3%.
Now a days, one can lock in a very safe long term withdrawal rate of over 4%. This is a very attractive rate of return for near or current retirees.
Not so much for those not near retirement as the long-term return of the S&P500 is the goal.

If a person has some funds that are being set aside for either a specific purpose in a year or two, or the funds are for a life-happens or emergency purposes, then the T-bills may meet the needs.
These are funds that would have been kept in a bank account because there was no desire to put them at risk. The tax issue would be better, if the interest earned was taxed at the long term capital gains rate, but even at the higher rate it is still way ahead of bank savings account interest rates.

Thanks, that makes sense. I should've clarified that the question is about purchasing etfs like BOXX (that actually allow an investor to achieve the long term capital gains rate) instead of rolling T-bills.
